# Protinet I/O Controller

Tags: ethernet

I need the Profinet I/O Controller. Do you know any controller ?

I have a profinet slave device which is send some profinet packet. I need the profinet master or configuration program to make understandable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic

Comment: Actually I need software so this is not shopping. I am looking for python or another application.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless Profinet Masters on the market. On the one hand, standalone hardware solutions or pure software solutions that you can run on the PC.

Profinet is a SIEMENS dominated development and therefore popular in Germany, Europe, China ... So SIEMENS is the right address for you. As an inexpensive device, I would recommend an S7-1211C.

Alternatively, you can install a Beckhoff TwinCAT Runtime on the PC. This installs a Profinet network driver so that you can control Profinet devices from your PC.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually I want to find the software solution or software application. I want to analyse the profinet data so I need master solution. I am looking for the python solution. Do you know any free and cheap software ?

Comment: I tried with the TwinCAT2 but I didnt how can I do this ? Could you help me ?